# InverseFunction's domain is not the range of the function that was inverted

Tags: function-construction, inverse, astronomy

I wrote a function to calculate how long of a period has past when a planet traverses an angle theta from perihelion in an orbit of a given eccentricity.

```
Integrate[(1 - 0.0167^2)^1.5/(2 Pi)  1/(1 + 0.0167 Cos [theta])^2, theta]
```

> ```
> 0.159088 (2.00084 ArcTan[0.983437 Tan[0.5 theta]] - (1.00028 Sin[theta]) /  
>    (59.8802 + 1. Cos[theta]))
> ```

The domain around the origin of the formula above is `-Pi ~ Pi` so I defined

```
s[theta_] := formula above /; 0 <= theta < Pi; 
s[theta_] := formula above + 1 /; Pi < theta <= 2Pi;
```

To get how the angle varies with time, I applied `InverseFunction` to `s` and got the inverse function `theta[t]`. When I input `theta[0.25]`, I get a numerical result but a `s^{-1}[0.99]` when input `theta[0.99]`.

Where's the point?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that `InverseFunction[s][0.99]` doesn't work here, but the following seems to work fine:

```
s = Function[theta, Piecewise[
  {{0.159088*(2.00084*ArcTan[0.983437*Tan[0.5*theta]] - (1.00028*Sin[theta])/
       (59.8802 + 1.*Cos[theta])), Inequality[0, LessEqual, theta, Less, Pi]}, 
   {1 + 0.159088*(2.00084*ArcTan[0.983437*Tan[0.5*theta]] - (1.00028*Sin[theta])/
        (59.8802 + 1.*Cos[theta])), Inequality[Pi, Less, theta, LessEqual, 2*Pi]}}, 0]];

InverseFunction[s] /@ {0.99, 0.25}

Out[27]= {6.21821, 1.60419}
```

If you want to inject your formula into the `Function` without having to copy-paste, this is how you can do it:

```
s = Block[{
   formula := 0.159088 (2.00084 ArcTan[0.983437 Tan[0.5 theta]] - (1.00028 Sin[theta])/(59.8802 + 1. Cos[theta])),
   theta
  },
  Function[theta,
   Evaluate@Piecewise[{
      {
       formula, 
       0 <= theta < Pi
       },
      {
       formula + 1, 
       Pi < theta <= 2 Pi
       }
      }
     ]
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: Many thanks! It indeed works! I hope one day the problem can be  solved.